# How do you know if user_login_submit was successful in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, users

Based on the answer from this question [How do I programmatically log in a user?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5825/how-do-i-programmatically-log-in-a-user)

I know how to login in a user, but is there a way to test if user_login_submit was successful or not? It does not have a return value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check if user is logged in or not by using global $user variable, if user is not logged in then $user->uid will be 0 for anonymous users.

Comment: I would up vote you to but I can not. Thanks a ton.

Comment: my pleasure.. :)