# Drupal sending SPAM, can't log in anymore

Tags: users, advertising

My unupdated drupal website has been sending large amounts of spam. I have now blocked the website with HTTP Basic authentication, but I can't seem to get in my admin account of the website. I've tried setting a new hash, but logging does not seem to work, as I don't get any error message when trying to.

Also the password reset function and create new account function do not work, I've tried showing error messages in my template.php file, etc.

Do any of you have any experience with this kind of hack? My Drupal was unupdated and is currently on version 7.15. How do I get back in? Or is it best to set up a new site and transfer the content.

[UPDATE] I have currently updated my drupal system to the most recent version, 7.30. But still no success. I can still not login, even though all the files are renewed. I have also reverted back to the garland theme, but also this theme is not giving me any error messages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't log in? Did you try 'drush uli' command?

Comment: Lesson learnt! Update Drupal :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to log in programmatically using a theme function, explained in this post.

[How do I programmatically log in a user?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5825/how-do-i-programmatically-log-in-a-user)