# login programmatically with remember me feature

Tags: 7, users

I'm trying to create a custom login form, since I need it to be ajax based. And I can't use the existing modules that do this. So far I have achieved this by setting the `global $user` object to the loaded user and calling `user_login_finalize()`. But now I need to make the login persist and I have no idea how the default drupal login does it. Any tips are appreciated. Thanks

### UPDATE:

The duplicate question indicated by [Pontus Nilsson](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/8948/pontus-nilsson) does not mention in any way how to make the login persist nor how to use the default drupal remember me or the [RememberMe](https://www.drupal.org/project/remember_me) module functionality.

### UPDATE 2:

I must elaborate that I have installed Remember Me module to make the persistent login optional for the user. Is that a reason why I needed to go through all this hassle explained in my answer to make the programmatical login persist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically log in a user?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5825/how-do-i-programmatically-log-in-a-user)

Comment: Where does it exactly answer my question there?

Comment: I guess you were a little bit quick with the duplicate button lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I accomplished the remember me feature. Since I didn't find any specific resources on this matter, the proposed solution may or may not be optimal and correct, although it works fine.

You use the following code to login a user programmatically:

```
$user = user_load($uid);
$login_array = array ('name' => $user_first_query->name);
user_login_finalize($login_array);
```

After that you have to decide whether to persist the login or not using the provided check box in the login form:

```
//at this point we need to persist the login by saving the user again
//with the remember_me data. But doing so, resets the user picture.
//So we need to preserve it somehow.
$user_picture_id = $user->picture;
if($_POST['remember_me']) {
    user_save($user, array('data' => array('remember_me' => (int)$_POST['remember_me'])));
}
else {
    unset($user->data['remember_me']);
    user_save($user, array());
}

//restore the user picture id
db_update('users')
    ->fields(array(
         'picture' => $user_picture_id,
    ))
    ->condition('uid', $uid)
    ->execute();
```

For the part where I have done `unset($user->data['remember_me']);` I have made sure that the rememeber_me data does not exist from a previous login. I think this should be done in the `modulename_user_presave()` hook but I couldn't implement it there.

Remember that since the main question is how to persist a user login, I have not provided a full login procedure, for example you should authenticate the user's credentials using the `user_authenticate()` function.