# How to get into a Drupal 7 site using only Drush without touching code or anything else?

Tags: 7, drush, users

I'm working on a acquia site and right now the dev environment is replicated from the prod. I want to be able to get in as admin on the dev site, but every time i hit the /user path it redirects me back to the prod site. I tried doing a **drush uli admin** but that doesnt work neither as I still get redirected back to prod. However, I am logged in as admin on the prod by doing a drush uli admin.

Without touching any of the code/files to get me logged into the dev site and only using Drush. How can one get in logged as admin?

Keep in mind there's no way to get to the /user path on dev as it redirects you once you land on there. And I'm not sure which modules/files is doing this functionality.

I was thinking of copying the cookie session from the prod database and then copy it into the dev database to simulate myself as being logged in, but I'm not sure how to go about that or what else might be needed.

Comment: Sounds like you have a custom redirect, that'll probably either be in code or the database. If it's in the database you can run a query (or set a variable) via drush, if it's in code you're out of luck

Comment: Is the $base_url hardcoded in settings.php?

Comment: how do you view the $base_url in settings.php when it resides on the acquia servers?

Comment: You have a local settings.php too @duckx

Answer (score 0):

What I did was change the default theme to the basic seven theme:

**drush @mydomain.dev vset theme_default seven**

Then reset your admin password:

**drush @mydomain.dev upwd admin --password="mypass"**

Then go and find a page that loads the seven theme and by default the seven theme has the login block somewhere in the footer area. Login with admin and your new pass! =D

If you have a theme switching module, you'll have to turn that off too. Such as **themekey** or **rules** or **securepages** (this is what was causing my issue.)

Answer (score 0):

Use drush to get a list of enabled modules except for core:

```
drush pm-list --type=Module --no-core
```

If the module Rename Admin Paths is being used then you can use drush to temporarily disable it until you are logged in.

ie.

```
drush pm-disable rename_admin_paths
```

or

```
drush dis rename_admin_paths
```

I'm suggesting this as that particular module in known to be one of the causes of redirects involving administrators and the /user path.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following workarounds:

- `/user/login` instead of just `/user`
- try: `drush uli` and try both `http://` and `https://`, maybe it could make a difference, or adding `?foo` at the end of the URI
- give every session an admin: `drush sqlq "UPDATE sessions SET uid = 1"` (make sure your browser session is included already there)
- hack `index.php` by adding the following line just after `drupal_bootstrap()`

  ```
  global $user; $user = user_load(1); session_start(); user_login_finalize();
  ```

  See also: [How do I programmatically log in a user?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/5825/1908)
- create a dummy session and hijack the cookie in the browser:

  ```
  $ drush eval 'global $user; session_start(); user_login_finalize(); echo session_name();'
  $ drush sqlq "UPDATE sessions SET uid = 1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1"
  ```

  then in the browser address bar type (to set the cookie):

  ```
  javascript:document.cookie="SESS37XXX=NGnGrXXX"
  ```